# Python Validation code not wroking

Tags: python, validation, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having some problems with this Python code I created in order to validate someone entering their email twice, and them checking to see if they have actually entered something and then to check if they match, and then finally to check if they both contain the "@" symbol. I'm still fairly new to python and I'm confused at the moment.

```
if len(email1) == 0 or len(email2) == 0:
    if email1 != email2:
        while "@" not in email1 or "@" not in email2:
            print "Your email is not valid!"
            email1 = raw_input("\nPlease enter your email address")
            time.sleep(1)
            email2 = raw_input("\nPlease re-enter your email address")
            delay_print("Validating Email......")
        else:
            print "Email accepted!"
    else:
        pass
else:
    f.write(email1)
```

Can someone help me with this code?

Comment: You don't tell us wrong the problem is.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you are assuming if two matching strings contain an @ then they must be valid email addresses?

Comment: Yes basically I want to make sure that both strings actually contain anything, and that they are both the same and then finally if they both contain "@" in them

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try something like

```
while not email1 or not email1 == email2 or not '@' in email1:
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you use instead [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

```
import re
import time
regex=re.compile("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+")

validMail=False
while not validMail:
    email1 = raw_input("\nPlease enter your email address ")
    email2 = raw_input("\nPlease re-enter your email address ")

    if len(email1)>0 and len(email2) > 0:
        if regex.search(email1) and regex.search(email2):
            if email1 == email2:
                print "Email accepted!"
                validMail=True
            else:
                print "different mail"
        else:
            print "Your email is not valid!"
    else:
        print "empty email"
```

Comment: Regex isn't a good tool for checking emails.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Ok, regex and email confirmation

Comment: I'm not using this for anything complex it's literally just a little school project to then write the entries into a file if they are true. However still being new I hadn't covered much of nested while loops or anything more complex